# login form submit button responsitivity issue?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have coded a login form but it has responsitivity issues with it's submit button and along I want the padding inside the form to decrease also. I do know media queries but I don't want to use those so if you people can propose a solution without using media queries as :

```css
/* VMS Forms ((START)) */

.vms-form-container {
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.vms-form-container a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.vms-form-footer a:hover {
 color: white;
}

.vms-form-footer a:visited {
 color: white;
}

.vms-form {
 text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #a68888;
    padding: 9% 17% 8% 17%;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.vms-form-footer {
 text-align: center;
    padding: 7% 17% 7% 17%;
    background-color: rgb(37, 80, 87);
    color: white;
}

.vms-form-inner {
 margin-top: 37px;
}

.vms-form-inner input {
 display: block;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding: 7px;
 width: 73%;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #d6cfcf;
}

.vms-form-inner input:focus {
 border: 1px solid rgb(221,129,126);
}

.vms-form-inner .vms-form-submit {
 background-color: rgb(199, 109, 106);
 display: block;
 padding: 7px 121px 7px 121px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.vms-form-inner .vms-form-submit span {
 position: absolute;
    margin-top: -25px;
    margin-left: 130px;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(184, 98, 95);
    padding: 5px 11px 5px 11px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.vms-form-inner a {
 text-align: right;
    display: block;
    width: 342px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.vms-form-title {
 font-size: 175%;
    color: #483535;
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.vms-form-title-bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.vms-form-title-bottom-border {
    width: 80px;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #483535;
}



/* VMS Forms ((END)) */
```

```html
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 60px;padding-bottom: 60px;">

 <!-- VMS Form -->
 <div class="vms-form-container col-sm-8">
  <div class="vms-form">
   <div class="vms-form-title">
    VENUE <span class="vms-form-title-bold">LOGIN</span>
   </div>
   <div class="vms-form-title-bottom-border"></div>
   <div class="vms-form-inner">
    <form>
     <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
     <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
     <br>
     <button type="submit">
     <div class="vms-form-submit">LOGIN <span>✔</span></div>
     </button>
     <a href="#!">> Forgot Password ? Reset</a>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vms-form-footer">
   <a href="#!">
    <img src="../images/vms/icon-vms-form-footer.png">
    > or create an account
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT IN ALL SCREENS :**

[image]

Comment: should the login button always have the same size as the inputs?

Comment: @ManuelOtto : Yes please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it by giving the login button a width attribute just like with the inputs.
Also style the button directly instead of putting a styled div inside.

```css
.vms-form-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.vms-form-container a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.vms-form-footer a:hover {
    color: white;
}
.vms-form-footer a:visited {
    color: white;
}
.vms-form {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #a68888;
    padding: 9% 17% 8% 17%;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.vms-form-footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7% 17% 7% 17%;
    background-color: rgb(37, 80, 87);
    color: white;
}
.vms-form-inner {
    margin-top: 37px;
}
.vms-form-inner input {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 73%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #d6cfcf;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.vms-form-inner input:focus {
    border: 1px solid rgb(221, 129, 126);
}
.vms-form-inner .vms-form-submit {
    background-color: rgb(199, 109, 106);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 73%;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
}
.vms-form-inner .vms-form-submit span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    width: 14px;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(184, 98, 95);
    padding: 5px 11px 5px 11px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.vms-form-inner a {
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    width: 342px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.vms-form-title {
    font-size: 175%;
    color: #483535;
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.vms-form-title-bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.vms-form-title-bottom-border {
    width: 80px;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #483535;
}
```

```html
<!-- VMS Form -->
 <div class="vms-form-container col-sm-8">
  <div class="vms-form">
   <div class="vms-form-title">
    VENUE <span class="vms-form-title-bold">LOGIN</span>
   </div>
   <div class="vms-form-title-bottom-border"></div>
   <div class="vms-form-inner">
    <form>
     <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
     <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
     <br>
     <button type="submit" class="vms-form-submit">
     LOGIN
     <span>✔</span></div>
     </button>
     <a href="#!">> Forgot Password ? Reset</a>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vms-form-footer">
   <a href="#!">
    <img src="../images/vms/icon-vms-form-footer.png">
    > or create an account
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
```